# Take the data from a worksheet, copy the contents to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I wish to copy a table and move it across to a new worksheet.  The table has buttons at the end of each row that activate separate macros.  The process of moving the data to the new worksheet needs to be controlled by VBA code.  I have code that creates the new worksheet

```
Sub CreateNewWS()
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.name=_WorksheetFunction.Text(New(), "dd - MM - yyyy")
End Sub
```

What I'd like to do is incorporate some code within this sub to copy the table and move it to the new worksheet "dd-mm-yyyy"

The table covers cells A5:M16 alternatively if it is easier a direct copy of the entire worksheet would be acceptable.  I've tried finding some code to perform this function but everything I've found hasn't worked and my knowledge of VBA is not enough to understand exactly what that code was trying to do.  If it makes any difference, the macro at the end of each row in the table will take the contents of the row and write it to a data file on another worksheet then wipe the row clean.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Skip

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)` will copy entire sheet and put it at the end

Comment: Hi AntiDrondert,  Thanks for your response, this worked well after removing some redundant commands in my original code.  Apologies for not responding quicker, I've been away from my office for a couple of days.  Thanks for the help.  Skip